# webpack and glTF files

Tags: webpack, three.js, blender, gltf

IM using three js and trying to import a 3d model from blender, Im also using webpack with it. Im trying to load in a glb file but cant get it working. It is now adding the file to the dist folder on build but it is not changing the path to the file (in the javascript file).

Heres my files:

webpack config

```
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    watch: true,

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                loader: 'html-loader',
            },
            {
              test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|glb|gltf)$/i,
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                  publicPath: './',
              },
          },
          {
            test: /\.glb$/,
            loader: '@vxna/gltf-loader',
            options: { inline: true },
          },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new htmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: './index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

javascript file im importing to

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import gsap from "gsap";
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import model from './fx.glb'


const scene = new THREE.Scene()
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000)
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()

init()
const geometry= createShape()
scene.add(geometry)
const loader = new GLTFLoader()
loader.load('./fx.glb',(model)=>{
  scene.add(model)
})
```

Any idea what im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
         {
          test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|glb|gltf)$/i,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
              publicPath: './',
              name: '[name].[ext]'
          },
```

Comment: A `.gltf` file might also reference one or more `.bin` files — not sure if webpack needs to be configured for that, too?

Comment: Yeah i think it does, None of the gltf loaders i have tried has worked yet

Comment: I found this question while trying to get around the same issue -- I figure the OP got it solved in the end, but since there's no accepted answer, I wanted to add that @DonMcCurdy got me pointed in the right direction. To bundle a .glb instead of .gltf I'm using:  `{ test: /\.(glb|bin)$/, loader: 'file-loader', options: { esModule: false } }`

Comment: This is also what I did

Answer (score 0):

I`m tried to use any `gltf-loaders` without results. This part of webpack configuration is working
for my example

```
{
     test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|bin|gif|glb|gltf)$/,
     loader: 'file-loader',
     options: {
      esModule: false
    }
   },
```

here is [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-kyy13)

Answer (score 0):

Using Webpack you need to import the .glb file first and then use the reference when loading it using the three.js GLTFLoader.

Change the following part to:

```
import model from './fx.glb'

const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load(model,(gltf)=>{
  scene.add(gltf.scene);
});
```

Configure the Loader like @sid already answered. I'll leave a copy here:

```
{
  test: /\.(gltf|glb|fbx|bin)$/i,
  use: [{
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      outputPath: 'assets/models',
      limit: false,
      name: '[name].[ext]'
    }
  }],
  type: 'javascript/auto'
},
```